# AR Object is moving with the camera in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality

i create a GameObject in unity where my GPS is,and setting the unity camera with the GPS after I convert it to xyz
here is my problem:
when I move the android device the created GameObject moves with the device but I need it to be in the position it created with.

```
 GameObject TempGameObject=GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            TempGameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
            TempGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z + 5f);
```

Comment: What game object is the above script attached to?

Comment: it's attached with my AR camera game object

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, it doesn't look like it's attaching the sphere to your camera as a child so that wasn't it. For AR you don't have to specify the object should be anchored to the real world plane? Or you could try making the object a child of the real world plane your phone finds (floor/wall/table etc.) so it will stay put.

Comment: thanks for your reply,i see your point here but for GPS based AR the idea is right to put the objects at GPS coordinate (after convert it to xyz) and put it in unity right?do you know any indoor location techniques that the accurcy is good?